# After updating Notes client / designer help navigator is broken

Tags: lotus-notes

Last week I tried to update my Notes client installation from 9.0.1 FP9 to FP10 IF 3. For technical reasons I had to roll back which proved to be quite difficult, and I ended up completely uninstalling Notes and doing a fresh installation of 9.0.1 (standard) then FP9 IF 2.

Everything's fine (and much more responsive than before, too) with one serious exception:

Within the client help popup window for Notes client and Domino Designer help is hardly usable now; obviously there's no CSS style or whatever applied to the nav page / frame:

[image: screenshot of help window]

As you can see in the screenshot styling of the main window part (green frame) is fine. But everything that is releated to navigation (red frames) appears to be raw html. Javascript calls are apparently working but it's really hard to navigate the "chapters". Same applies to Designer help, of course.

Here's what I tried to solve that riddle:

- uninstalled and re-installed full client 3 times; sometimes I ran the
  installation as local Admin other times I didn't (no difference)
- just installed plain Notes 9.0.1 from scratch then tested Client help before updating to FP9IF2 (no difference)
- restored the entire [Notes-Programm]\framework directory from a
  backup I took when Notes help still was working as expected (no difference)
- copied over the entire \Notes\ folder from a different PC where popup help is still working fine (no difference)

Problem with that is: being a Developer I need to have a functioning help window in my Domino Designer. The navigator as it is right now however is plain useless. And designer_help.nsf isn't of help at all when it comes to Java, LotusScript etc. objects and classes.

One of my co-workers has the same phenomenon while another one hasn't.

Question: did anyone else experience something like that? Where you able to solve it? How?

Comment: Sorry I can't help, I too have that on one machine but not on another, very frustrating. I have rolled back from FP10 on each machine, FP10 was a nightmare for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I restored my entire Windows system partition from a backup created just before all that began (lucky me that I have both regular local backups plus a separate system partition). And that finally helped resolve the problem.

Meanwhile I'm 99% sure that this is due to a rather new registry and/or firewall setting not yet known to IBM's NICE tool.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to an issue with the embedded browser windows that Domino Designer uses to open the Help website.

Try to open following link in a modern browser (such as Chrome or Firefox) and the navigation should be fine.

http://localhost:50970/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes.help.doc%2Ffram_getting_started_c.html

Bookmark it and use it when you need it.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, as I wrote in my own answer 2 years ago this prob doesn't exist any longer, at least not on my machine. Nevertheless thanks for your input. That's an interesting info, indeed! Checked it on my machine; found that in my case the IP port is different from yours. Easy to find the correct port, though: open the internal help pop-up and hover one of the navigator topics; in the status line at the bottom we can see the correct port number

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IBM Nice tool to see if it can fix your issue

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21459714

Comment: Thanks, but I did already 3 or 4 times. No help, though I'm sure that this must be due to some registry entries, most probably not known to Nice which wasn't updated for a while. I also had the idea that it could be due to some Firewall settings but even completely disabling FW didn't help. I plan to do a complete Windows rollback over the weekend, if that doesn't help I'll give up and hope for Domino 10

Comment: It may be a long shot, but if your Notes client / designer is all working and "just" the help isn't working, try to check where the required js / css are on your pc and compare with your colleague's ?   The help is just hosted locally on your PC , url to table of contents  would be something like http://localhost:xxxx/help/advanced/tocView.jsp?view=toc                                                                                               <script language="JavaScript" src="helptree.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="helptreechildren.js"></script>  etc

Comment: Thanks again, and yes: I did check this already. URLs apeear to point to a zip file under my local <notes-prog>/framework directory. So I did replace the entire dir content but it didn't help either - meanwhile I restored my entire Windows system partition as I pointed out earlier, and that DID help indeed. So I'll close this topic later on.